# Detecting JSplitPane Divider Movement

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

Is there a way to detect when a JSplitPane divider is moved?  Is there a way to add a listener for divider movement?

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, panel1, panel2);
// What do I put here to be notified if the divider in sp is moved?
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you're looking for [addPropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addPropertyChangeListener%28java.beans.PropertyChangeListener%29) from `Container`.  Something like this...

```
sp.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, 
    new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {}
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
splitter.addPropertyChangeListener("dividerLocation", myListener);
```

Comment: better use the `DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY` constant instead of the String itself